# Form Tags in View Not Outputted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

The form tags aren't displaying. (Really ripping my hair out over this.) I have a view (Index.cshtml):

```
@section mainmid
{    
  @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "PetSittingRequest"))
  {    
    <h1>    
      @Html.TextBox("awesome")
    </h1>      
  }    
}
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@RenderSection("mainmid", required: false)
@RenderBody()
```

The HTML that I'm getting is this. It has no form tags. They're not located anywhere in the HTML source.

```
<h1>    
  <input id="awesome" name="awesome" type="text" value="" />
</h1>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read this? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652944/html-beginform-output-not-rendered-if-preceded-by-renderpage Might have something to do with it idk

Comment: That seems to be it. I had the same scenario, changed it to Html.Partial() and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Impossible to reproduce. Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project
2. In `_Layout.cshtml` replace `@RenderBody()` with:

   ```
   @RenderSection("mainmid", required: false)
   @RenderBody()
   ```
3. In `Index.cshtml` put the following:

   ```
   @section mainmid
   {    
       @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "PetSittingRequest"))
       {    
           <h1>    
               @Html.TextBox("awesome")
           </h1>      
       }    
   }
   ```
4. Run the application
5. Browse the source and you will find the correct HTML rendered:

   ```
   <form action="/PetSittingRequest" method="post">    
       <h1>    
           <input id="awesome" name="awesome" type="text" value="" />
       </h1>      
   </form>
   ```

Conclusion: your problem lies somewhere else. So next time you ask a question please provide a full example allowing to reproduce the problem (as I did in my answer).